# Java interceptors, confused about @InterceptorBinding

Tags: java, annotations, interceptor

I'm playing with interceptors and annotations but I'm pretty confused and I cannot find a extensive tutorial. 
Actually I don't understand the difference between this:

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation {}
```

and this:

```
@Inherited
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation {}
```

what @InterceptorBinding do? Why use it and why not?

I'm searching for some good how-tos with examples about annotations and interceptors, covering different use cases, but I've found documentation about very basic usages or some cryptic code (at least for me) without any explanation, so thank you if you can give me some pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider interceptor declaration:

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface Logged {
}
```

**@InterceptorBinding** is just an indicator that used to bind annotations to specific interceptor.

> Along with an interceptor, an application defines one or more interceptor binding types, which are annotations that associate an interceptor with target beans or methods. For example, the billpayment example contains an interceptor binding type named @Logged and an interceptor named LoggedInterceptor.

**@Inherited** is used to allow this annotation down by class hierarchy.

> An interceptor binding also has the java.lang.annotation.Inherited annotation, to specify that the annotation can be inherited from superclasses. The @Inherited annotation also applies to custom scopes (not discussed in this tutorial), but does not apply to qualifiers.

Also take a look at [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhjx.html) .